# A Question on Calculus of Variation

Tags: calculus, integration, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, variational-analysis

Find the extremal of the Functional $J[y(x)]=\int_{0}^{1}(2e^{y}-y^{2})dx$ subject to $y(0)=1$ and $y(1)=e$.

Using Euler's equation we get the answer $y=e^{y}$.

My question is how to check the boundary condition? Is this actually a solution to the original problem? In general how to tackle a problem in which the answer obtained through Euler's equation does not contain x?

Comment: Shouldn’t the quadratic term be $y’^2$ instead of $y^2$ in your original functional.

Comment: No. The question has just $y^{2}$ and not $y'^{2}$.